# Does one page LOR hurt my chance of getting to graduate school

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I recently asked from the professor whom I have done research with him and I also did great in his class for LOR. He agreed to write a positive letter of recommendation for me however when I talked to him further he said his letter is going to be one page double spaced. I am thinking this is really short letter according to some pages in the internet and also a post in this page

[How long should letters of recommendation for students be?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5061/how-long-should-letters-of-recommendation-for-students-be)

Do you think this will hurt my chance of getting into top graduate school in US?

Comment: Note that my answer to [the linked question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5061/how-long-should-letters-of-recommendation-for-students-be) was about letters of recommendation for graduating Ph.D. students, rather than applicants to grad school.  Letters for grad school applicants are usually shorter, since there's less to say.  One page double spaced is still on the short side, but it won't be a disaster (especially if your letters aren't all that length).

Comment: How long letter to graduate school is on average?

Comment: My letters of recommendation for graduate school are typically one to two pages long, so this doesn't seem unreasonable to me.  For an undergraduate student there typically isn't much to say about the student's research experience (other than perhaps that the student participated in an REU program), so these letters tend to be more about what courses the student has taken and how the student compares to his/her classmates.

Comment: Thanks. When you say one or two pages do you mean  double-space or single space?

Answer (score 1):

One page double-space sounds like your professor is willing to say good things, but doesn't have all that much to say.  That's not going to be a particularly strong letter of recommendation, but it's better than not having a letter.